# Activity doesn't start after it started once

Tags: android

My project starts an activity (say A) from `Application` class, some option in the activity A needs to launch another activity (say B), now depends on some network conditions, `application` class may need to start activity A (currently activity B is shown). but this time (this is the second time that activity B is going to start) activity B is not shown. I use the following code to start activity:

```
Intent main_act= new Intent(app.this,main_activity.class);
startActivity(main_act);
```

Comment: improve your question and post all code.

Comment: are using the back button to go previous activity ?

Comment: Your post is not clear. Provide more information and a full code example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android will resurface an existing activity by default, you can add `android:launchMode="singleTask"` to your activity in the manifest and that should get you closer to the functionality you're expecting.